# Android Studio - SoundPool - stop the sound after taking off the finger from ImageView

Tags: android, audio, android-studio, ontouchlistener, soundpool

I have an ImageView. When I touch it, the color changes and the censor sound starts playing. When I take off finger from the ImageView, the color is changed again and the sound should stop playing.

Everything works fine but the sound won't stop. I tried to put the stop() method into the OnClickListener but it didn't work.

How can I stop sound when I take off a finger from ImageView?

```
btn_censor.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener {
@override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        btn_censor.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_censor_focus);//Change color of the ImageView

        //Parameters for sound
        float vol = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float maxVol = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float leftVolume = vol / maxVol;
        float rightVolume = vol / maxVol;
        int priority = 1;
        int loop = -1; //infinite loop
        float normal_plaback_rate = 1f;

        soundPool.play(censor_ID, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, loop, normal_playback_rate);//Play the sound
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        btn_censor.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_censor);//Change colour of the ImageView
        soundPool.stop(censor_ID);//This should stop the sound
    }
    return false;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass censor_ID for stop(). The follow code works for me:

```
int streamID;

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      streamID = soundPool.play(myLoadedSoundID, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      soundPool.stop(streamID);
    }
    return true;
  }
```